# Differences in 90% tested with 5 , 10 , 20 , 30 and 50 Vusers

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, loadrunner, neoload

Tested the web based application using JMeter with 5, 10 , 20 , 30 and 50 Vusers and duration is 15 minutes and report got generated as below .

so for the Transaction Name MyQuotation_T03 for 90% and 20 Vuser response time is less than 10 Vuser response time , 30 Vuser response time is less than 20 Vuser response time , 50 Vuser response time is less than 20 Vuser response time.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBl3o.png)

Why this fluctuation occurs and if client asked me  response times should be like this 5<10<20<30<50   but in the report it is viceversa so how can I answer to this question? Why like this happened?

Could anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the case there is no difference between 10 and 50 users as the "load" you're putting on the system under test is some form of a [statistical noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy_data)

Try re-running your test with 100 -> 200 -> 300 users or even better start with 1 user and [gradually increase the load](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-period) until response time start growing or errors start occurring, whatever comes the first. In other words run a [stress test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_performance_testing#Stress_testing), in this case you will be able to correlate increasing load with increasing response time. It might also be the case your application scales up to handle the incoming load and response time won't increase at all but instead the number of new instances will be kicked off so you might want to measure the [scalability factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability_testing#Outcomes_of_scalability_testing) and/or resources consumption instead of response time

Answer (score 0):

The more samples you have in your data set the higher the quality of the reporting.  Assuming that all of your users execute at the same number of cycles per user per hour, then 10 users will produce half the data set of 20 users, which is again half again of 40 users, and so on.

As your data set increases the integrity of the statistical data gets better.  This applies to all statistical data, average, mode, standard deviation, any percentile value, maximum, etc...   This is where your college stats class really pays off.  How long do you need to run your test to have a large enough data set to obtain statistically valid data for analysis?